# How do I link an IntelliJ IDEA project to a local git repository?

Tags: eclipse, git, intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ and trying to switch from Eclipse to IntelliJ.

In Eclipse it's done by creating a workspace and then importing the local repository. The workspace is separate from the repository. The workspace only reference the repository.

I want to do this in IntelliJ. I think the setup would be something like the project located in e.g. `C:\Projects\MyProgram\` with `MyProgram` having `.idea` in it. The actual code for MyProgram would be in e.g. `C:\Repos\MyProgram.git`. The repository would only contain code, not config files for the IntelliJ project. Alternatively I'd like to know how this is typcially done with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is done<sup>1</sup> as follows:

1. `git clone` your repo (if you don't already have it locally).
2. In Intellij, open or import the root repo folder as a project.
3. Add `.idea/` (or `*.iml` as appropriate) to your `.gitignore` file.

I'm not sure if there's a good reason for trying to keep the IntelliJ files in a different part of your filesystem.<sup>2</sup>  Some of the [advice out there](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2013/09/24/separating-ide-wkspcs-code-repos/) regarding Eclipse concerns the semantics of workspaces, which don't exist in IntelliJ.

---

<sub>1. To be more precise, this is how **I** typically do it :)</sub>

<sub>2. Although I'm happy to be convinced otherwise!</sub>

Comment: I don't want duplication of the repository, I want it in one place. I'm not trying to convince anyone about anything. But you may want to check out this blog post:
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2013/09/24/separating-ide-wkspcs-code-repos/

Comment: @Seiten - Oh, I'm not suggesting you duplicate anything.  If you already have a local clone of the repo, then Step #1 above is unnecessary :)

Comment: @Seiten - That article is about Eclipse.  It's been 5 years since I last used Eclipse, so I can't comment on the specifics.  But IntelliJ doesn't have the same concept of Workspaces, so I'm not sure that it applies to IntelliJ.

Comment: The article contains general arguments why it's a good idea to separate IDE specific stuff from the repository.  That's what I was asking how to do in IntelliJ. I don't want my repository cluttered with IntelliJ stuff, even if I can .gitignore it.

Comment: @Seiten - I see.  Well, this answer addresses the "how this is typically done" part of your question.  I imagine it's possible to separate the IntelliJ files, but I never do it personally.  (IMHO, a repo will typically be cluttered with all sorts of stuff - build output, runtime output, log files, etc.  Thus IntelliJ files are no better or worse than all that stuff.)

Comment: Should I add the .idea dir to .gitignore?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162627/discussion-between-seiten-and-oliver-charlesworth).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a different content root in the "More Settings" while creating a project. This location is the one where you have your repository.

[image]

Comment: I only get Project format when I click More Settings. Not Module name, Content root etc.